# indices of occurence of each row in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, row, matching, indices

I have two matrices, `A` and `B`. (`B` is continuous like `1:n`)

I need to find all the occurrences of each individual row of `B` in `A`, and store those row indices accordingly in cell array `C`.  See below for an example.

```
A = [3,4,5;1,3,5;1,4,3;4,2,1]
B = [1;2;3;4;5]
```

Thus,

```
C = {[2,3,4];[4];[1,2,3];[1,3,4];[1,2]}
```

Note `C` does not need to be in a cell array for my application. I only suggest it because the row vectors of `C` are of unequal length.  If you can suggest a work-around, this is fine too.

I've tried using a loop running ismember for each row of `B`, but this is too slow when the matrices `A` and `B` are huge, with around a million entries.  Vectorized code is appreciated.

(To give you context, the purpose of this is to identify, in a mesh, those faces that are attached to a single vertex.  Note I cannot use the function edgeattachments because my data are not of the form "TR" in triangulation representation.  All I have is a list of faces and list of vertices.)

Comment: Is `B` always continuous like `1:n`? This would facilitate the work since you wouldn't need to check B in A, but check each row of A and fill the cell C as the indexes appears.

Comment: @Ashwin: Your expression for `C` is not valid, but I assume you mean `C = {[2,3,4];[4];[1,2,3];[1,3,4];[1,2]}`.  Is that right?  If so, see my answer.  Hope that helps.

Comment: @Werner, yes, that is correct.  I updated the problem statement with this detail.

Comment: @chappjc, yes, that is also correct.  Updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the best answer for this would require knowledge of how A is filled. If A is sparse, that is, if it has few columns values and B is quite large, then I think the best way for memory saving may be using a sparse matrix instead of a cell.

```
% No fancy stuff, just fast and furious 
bMax = numel(B);
nRows = size(A,1);

cLogical = sparse(nRows,bMax);

for curRow = 1:nRows
  curIdx = A(curRow,:);
  cLogical(curRow,curIdx) = 1;
end
```

Answer:

```
cLogical =

   (2,1)        1
   (3,1)        1
   (4,1)        1
   (4,2)        1
   (1,3)        1
   (2,3)        1
   (3,3)        1
   (1,4)        1
   (3,4)        1
   (4,4)        1
   (1,5)        1
   (2,5)        1
```

How to read the answer. For each column the rows show the indexes that the column index appears in A. That is `1` appears in rows `[2 3 4]`, `2` appear in row `[4]`, `3` rows `[1 2 3]`, `4` row `[1 3 4]`, `5` in row `[1 2]`.

Then you can use `cLogical` instead of a cell as an indexing matrix in the future for your needs.

Another way would be to allocate C with the expected value for how many times an index should appear in C.

```
% Fancier solution using some assumed knowledge of A
bMax = numel(B);
nRows = size(A,1);
nColumns = size(A,2);

% Pre-allocating with the expected value, an attempt to reduce re-allocations.
% tic; for rep=1:10000; C = mat2cell(zeros(bMax,nColumns),ones(1,bMax),nColumns); end; toc 
% Elapsed time is 1.364558 seconds.
% tic; for rep=1:10000; C = repmat({zeros(1,nColumns)},bMax,1); end; toc
% Elapsed time is 0.606266 seconds.
% So we keep the not fancy repmat solution
C = repmat({zeros(1,nColumns)},bMax,1);
for curRow = 1:nRows
  curIdxMsk = A(curRow,:);
  for curCol = 1:nColumns
    curIdx = curIdxMsk(curCol);
    fillIdx = ~C{curIdx};
    if any(fillIdx) 
      fillIdx = find(fillIdx,1);
    else
      fillIdx = numel(fillIdx)+1;
    end
    C{curIdx}(fillIdx) = curRow;
  end
end

% Squeeze empty indexes:
for curRow = 1:bMax
  C{curRow}(~C{curRow}) = [];
end
```

Answer:

```
>> C{:}

ans =

     2     3     4


ans =

     4


ans =

     1     2     3


ans =

     1     3     4


ans =

     1     2
```

Which solution will performs best? You do a performance test in your code because it depends on how big is A, bMax, the memory size of your computer and so on. Yet, I'm still curious with solutions other people can do for this x). I liked  chappjc's solution although it has the cons that he has pointed out.

For the given example (10k times):

```
Solution 1: Elapsed time is 0.516647 seconds. 
Solution 2: Elapsed time is 4.201409 seconds (seems that solution 2 is a bad idea hahaha, but since it was created to the specific issue of A having many rows it has to be tested in those conditions).
chappjc' solution: Elapsed time is 2.405341 seconds.
```

Comment: Are your timings for a bigger example?  When I run my (memory inefficient) solution with the short original example, I get `Elapsed time is 0.000707 seconds.`.

Comment: @chappjc I forgot to tell that I ran it for 10k times.

Comment: Haha! That explains it.  But a more fair test would be to use larger data rather than more iterations.  `bsxfun` really starts to scream with bigger data, and will not help much when called repeatedly for short data.  Also, I've updated my answer with the sparse output option you suggested in your first answer.  That should be pretty speedy, but still no good for memory usage unfortunately.

Comment: @chappjc I just ran 10k times to remove possible time oscillations (I was running while listening to music and so on, those background process could interfere in the benchmark, but I didn't want to stop the music haha). And I didn't want to run for a big data also, it would be boring to create a data sample for this and to wait the process to run, it would be another thing to think and so on. OP can test performance and tell us what works best for his sample (something I would appreciate to know, together with the sizes of the original data).

Comment: @Werner, you solution #1 is exactly what I need. Very clever!  Thanks.

Comment: @AshwinJ.Shahani glad I could help x)

Answer (score 1):

We can do it without making any assumptions about `B`.  Try this use of `bsxfun` and `mat2cell`:

```
M = squeeze(any(bsxfun(@eq,A,permute(B,[3 2 1])),2)); % 4x3x1 @eq 1x1x5 => 4x3x5
R = sum(M); % 4x5 -> 1x5
[ii,jj] = find(M);
C = mat2cell(ii,R)
```

The cells in `C` above will be column vectors rather than rows as in your example.  To make the cells contain row vectors, use `C = mat2cell(ii',1,R)'` instead.

My only concern is that `mat2cell` could be slow for millions of values of `R`, but if you want your output in a cell, I'm not sure how much better you can do. **EDIT**: If you can deal with a sparse matrix like in Werner's first solution with the loop, replace the last line of the above with the following:

```
>> Cs = sparse(ii,jj,1)
Cs =
   (2,1)        1
   (3,1)        1
   (4,1)        1
   (4,2)        1
   (1,3)        1
   (2,3)        1
   (3,3)        1
   (1,4)        1
   (3,4)        1
   (4,4)        1
   (1,5)        1
   (2,5)        1
```

Unfortunately, `bsxfun` will probably run out of memory if *both* `size(A,1)` and `numel(B)` are large!  You may have to loop over the elements of `A` or `B` if memory becomes an issue.  Here's one way to do it by looping over your vertexes in `B`:

```
for i=1:numel(B), C{i} = find(any(A==B(i),2)); end
```

Yup, that easy.  Cell array growing is extremely fast in MATLAB as it similar to a sequence container that stores contiguous references to the data, rather than keeping the data itself contiguous.  Perhaps `ismember` was the bottleneck in your test.

Comment: Indeed, I am having memory issues with bsxfun...  And I should have specified: it doesn't have to be in a cell array.  I only suggested this format because the vectors in each row are of unequal length.  I think it would be fine if the other (empty) entries of C (matrix) are 0.  Thanks!